# Should access to files stored in an hsqldb database be serialized?

Tags: multithreading, file-io, hsqldb

Given:

1. One can access an HSQLDB database concurrently using connections pooled with the help of the apache commons dbcp package.
2. I store files in a cached table in an **embedded** hsqldb database.
3. It is known that files on a conventional hard drive (as opposed to a solid state) should not be accessed from multiple threads, because we are likely to get performance degradation rather than boost. This is because of the time it takes to move the mechanical reading head back and forth between the files with each thread context switch.

Question:

- Does this rule hold to files managed in an HSQLDB database? The file sizes may range from several KB to several MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HSQLDB accesses two files for data storage during operations. One file for all CACHED table data, and another file for all the lobs. It manages access to these files internally.

With multiple threads, there is a possibility of reduced access speed in the following circumstances.

1. Simultaneous read and write access to large tables.
2. Simultaneous read and write access to lobs larger than 500KB.